# How to check if all properties in object are undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to check if all properties of an object are undefined I tried this but this is always true because when one of them is undefined it is true:

```
// Check if property is undefined
for (var property in filters) {
  if (Object.keys(property).indexOf(undefined)) {
     return this.restaurantsList;
  }
}
```

The filters object looks like this:

```
{
   ishnationality: undefined
   dishtype: undefined
   organizeby: undefined
}
```

How can I simply check if all are undefined?

Comment: An objects key is always a string. Never ever `undefined` !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
  Object.values(filters).every(el => el === undefined)
```

You are actually looking for the objects values, not its keys.

Comment: values does not exist on type ObjectConstructor

Comment: @sreinieren use a more modern version of typescript or just ignore the error.

Comment: Use `"lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]` to get the definitions for `values`

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkForUndefined(object) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (object[key] !== undefined)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How about this function?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example evaluating the value of each property in the object:

```js
function allUndefined(obj){
  for(var p in obj) {
    if(obj[p] !== undefined){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var filtersAllUndefined = {
  ishnationality: undefined,
  x: undefined
}

console.log(allUndefined(filtersAllUndefined));

var filterSomeUndefined = {
  ishnationality: undefined,
  x: 3
}
console.log(allUndefined(filterSomeUndefined));
```